# apache poi does not exit after reading rows

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am reading a excel file which is confidential and the file does not exit after hitting the final row.Can you point out what I am doing wrong in the below code attached.Sorry can't attach confidential data excel.Actually I have only two rows header and some data on the next row,But the loop does not terminate after row 2.Goes to row 3 and Prints just One Cell and exits

Java File

```
public void readData(Workbook wb) {

        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        int rowCount=1;
        for(Row row: sheet1) {
            System.out.println("Reading Row:"+rowCount);
            Iterator<Cell> cellIter = row.cellIterator();
            while(cellIter.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIter.next();
                System.out.println("CELL VALUE:"+formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
            }
            rowCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Output

Reading Row:1

CELL VALUE:A

CELL VALUE:B

CELL VALUE:C

Reading Row:2

CELL VALUE:AA

CELL VALUE:BB

CELL VALUE:CC

Reading Row:3

CELL VALUE:

Answer (score 0):

Just even though the rows were blank,had to delete and recreate the bottom rows without data to make it work.